# How to run Spek tests with Maven?

Tags: maven, kotlin, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to run Spek tests with Maven. I have set up maven like this:

```
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

                <configuration/>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>
```

Additionally I have a few Spek tests in src/test/kotlin. I can run these fine within the IDE, but when I run `mvn test` they are completely ignored by the surefire plugin (it reports 0 tests being run). Is it possible to run Spek tests with maven and if so, how would this be set up? I cannot find anything about it on the spek homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue with a small sample project, that [you can find on GitLab.com](https://gitlab.com/pvorb/spek-maven-sample/tree/master).

If you run `mvn clean test`, surefire won't find any tests:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ spek-maven-sample ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.074 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-27T00:49:14+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/363M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This can be circumvented by explicitly including test specs in the Surefire plugin. Say, all your specs are named `*Spec.*`, then explicitly configuring surefire in your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- other build plugins like the kotlin-maven-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

will lead to executing tests

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ spek-maven-sample ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Dev\IDEA\spek-test\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running NonsenseTestableSpec
Proof that 'should return true' ran
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.077 sec

Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.335 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-27T01:02:12+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/363M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can find the full working example [on the branch "explicit-surefire-config"](https://gitlab.com/pvorb/spek-maven-sample/tree/explicit-surefire-config) of the mentioned repository.

Comment: Great, that did the trick for me as well. Thank you very much!